# Bringing alcohol to connection airport

Tags: dubai, uae, alcohol, jordan, amman

This summer I plan to visit my friends while traveling Sri Lanka and would like to bring them alcohol that is made in my country. I'm aware how much I can bring to Sri Lanka.
My question is if I need to check rules to bring alcohol to airports where I will have layover. Airports in question are ones in Amman(Jordan) and Dubai(UAE).
I wont leave airport.

*After comment section adding some additional information about flights:*

- First I fly to Amman via Wizz Air, have 6h55m Self-transfer.
- Than I
  fly to Dubai via Air Arabia, have 2h layover.
- Lastly to Colombo via
  Air Arabia.

Comment: The first question is: are you traveling on a single ticket from your home airport to Sri Lanka? Or have you purchased separate tickets for parts of your journey?

Comment: @PeterM Frankly as this is my first time traveling outside Eu and not having direct flight, I am not sure. I bought it thru kiwi and paid once. Not for every flight separately. Is there some distinction where I can find this information or too late at this point?

Comment: It all depends on the exact itinerary.  It would be helpful to list what airlines you are flying for each leg of the booking, and if you have a single PNR (Passenger Name Record) for the booking.  This determines whether you need to re-check your luggage  in Amman or Dubai.  But I just did a quick google, and it seems that there are not prohibitions on having alcohol and that there are duty free shops in both places selling alcohol. So it would appear that you will not have a problem. Because I have no direct experience with this, I'm leaving this as a comment and not an answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot I added additional information about flights to original post.

Comment: For clarity, how much alcohol are you intending to travel with? Anything over 100ml needs to go into checked baggage; the rules for taking alcohol into Amman differ to those for Dubai https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Any liquid in your carry on is limited to 100ml UNLESS there is exception for bottles bought in duty free
2. Checked baggage is generally fine.
3. Since you are self connection in Amman, you need to collect your bags and go through customs. Customs limit in Jordan for alcohol is 1 liter.
4. In Dubai you don't have to touch your luggage. You can buy alcohol in duty free and carry it on with you. It will be packed in a sealed transparent bag with the receipt visible.
5. Air Arabia is a "dry" airline. It's possible that they do not allow to carry on duty free alcohol. I recommend checking with them directly
6. In Sri Lanka you need to clear customs again. Limit is 1.5 liters of liquor.

Comment: it is 1.4liters in bottles ... so if I understand you corretly I wont have any problems with it in Amman since its not final destination?

Comment: @Whey no, you misunderstood. You will be entering Jordan so it will be exactly as if it was your final destination. A self-transfer means you have two different trips: one from your origin to Amman, and then a second one from Amman to your final destination. It so happens you only stay for a few hours in Amman, but for customs that doesn’t change anything, and for passport/visas Wizz Air will require tou to have the required documentation to enter Jordan (likely depends on your citizenship).

Comment: jcaron is correct: you need to meet the requirements for importing alcohol for BOTH Jordan AND  Sri Lanka. You have some leeway in Dubai, but that depends a bit on what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: Oh okey I understand now ... so it is like I feared it will be. Thanks a lot for answer and setting my mistake straight.